# Triangle with a median

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In the triangle $ABC$ the length of a median beginning in A is $\sqrt{10}$. If $|AB|=4$ and $|AC|=6$ what is the length of BC?

I tried using the law of cosines with different parts of the angle near A but without any significant results. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try Stewart's Theorem. It is

$$dad + man = bmb + cnc$$

where $d$ is the length of the median, and $m+n = a$ are the lengths created by the median to the side of length $a$.

Comment: Could you perhaps find a more "elementary" solution?

Comment: You can prove Stewart's with the Law of Cosines, if that makes it more elementary.

Comment: My bad. You're right. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know Apollonius' theorem?

Comment: Now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use *Al Kashi's theorem*: let $x=\frac 12 BC$ and $I$be the midpoint of $BC$. Applying Al Kashi's theorem in triangles  $AIB$ and $AIC$ yields
$$\begin{cases}
16=x^2+10-2\sqrt{10}x\\
36=x^2+10+2\sqrt{10}x
\end{cases}\enspace\text{ whence }\; 2\sqrt{10} x=x^2-6=26-x^2$$
so $\;x^2=16$ and eventually $BC=8$.